# How to update Notification with RemoteViews?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-remoteview

I'm creating a notification with [`RemoteViews`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews) from a custom `Service`, which is running with notification in a foreground mode (that is, service will remain active as long as notification is visible to user). Notification is set as Ongoing so user cannot swipe it off.

I'd like to change for example bitmap shown in `ImageView`, contained within remote view's layout or change text value in a `TextView`. Layout in remote view is set with XML layout file.

My problem is that once notification is created and visible to user, if I call any of `RemoteViews`'s functions like [`setImageViewResource()`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setImageViewResource(int,%20int)) to change `Bitmap` shown in an `ImageView`, the change is not visible, unless I do call `setImageViewResource()` I call afterwards:

```
NotificationManager.notify( id, notification );
```

or

```
Service.startForeground(id,notification);
```

This doesn't sound right to me though. I can't believe that to update `RemoteViews` UI in a notification that is already created, I have to re-initialize notification. If I have `Button` control in a notification, it updates itself on touch and release. So there's gotta be a way to do this properly, but I don't know how.

Here is my code which creates notification inside my `Service` instance:

```
this.notiRemoteViews = new MyRemoteViews(this,this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_noti1);

Notification.Builder notibuilder = new Notification.Builder(this.getApplicationContext());
notibuilder.setContentTitle("Test");
notibuilder.setContentText("test");
notibuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
notibuilder.setOngoing(true);

this.manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
this.noti = notibuilder.build();
this.noti.contentView = this.notiRemoteViews;
this.noti.bigContentView = this.notiRemoteViews;
this.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, this.noti);
```

And function that 'forces' UI changes to notification:

```
public void updateNotiUI(){
    this.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, this.noti);
}
```

Within `MyRemoteViews` class, when required, I do this to make changes to UI:

```
this.setImageViewResource(R.id.iconOFF, R.drawable.icon_off2);
this.ptMyService.updateNotiUI();
```

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way of updating UI components of a `RemoteViews` in the notification?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here's a detail example for you to update the notification using `RemoteViews`:

```
private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private RemoteViews mRemoteViews;
private Notification mNotification;
...

// call this method to setup notification for the first time
private void setUpNotification(){

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // we need to build a basic notification first, then update it
    Intent intentNotif = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intentNotif.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentNotif, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // notification's layout
    mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_small);
    // notification's icon
    mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_icon, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    // notification's title
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_title, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    // notification's content
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_content, getResources().getString(R.string.content_text));

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    CharSequence ticker = getResources().getString(R.string.ticker_text);
    int apiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (apiVersion < VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, ticker, System.currentTimeMillis());
        mNotification.contentView = mRemoteViews;
        mNotification.contentIntent = pendIntent;

        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
        mNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        // starting service with notification in foreground mode
        startForeground(NOTIF_ID, mNotification);

    }else if (apiVersion >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
                .setContent(mRemoteViews)
                .setTicker(ticker);

        // starting service with notification in foreground mode
        startForeground(NOTIF_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}

// use this method to update the Notification's UI
private void updateNotification(){

    int api = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    // update the icon
    mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_icon, R.drawable.icon_off2);
    // update the title
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_title, getResources().getString(R.string.new_title));
    // update the content
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_content, getResources().getString(R.string.new_content_text));

    // update the notification
    if (api < VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, mNotification);
    }else if (api >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Layout for the Notification, i.e. `res/layout/custom_notification_small.xml`:

```
<!-- We have to set the height to 64dp, this is the rule of the small notification -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/notif_small"
    android:background="@drawable/notification_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notif_icon"
        android:contentDescription="@string/notif_small_desc"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notif_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notif_icon"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notif_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notif_icon"
        android:paddingBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#575757"
        android:text="Content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this example helps you a lot!

NOTE: You can't update the custom `NotificationCompat` on pre-Honeycomb, so I added an alternative way to update it on pre-Honeycomb, i.e. checking the API level first and use the deprecated `Notification` instead.

Comment: Your Answer Is Correct But updateNotification() where we need to call

Comment: @Dilip, see my answer again. I have updated it, so you can understand more.

Comment: the only working solution for startForeground() RemoteView Notification updating. Awesome Answer.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH Hey Its giving me this error                       android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.areel.android: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.areel.android user=UserHandle{0} id=1234 tag=null key=0|com.areel.android|1234|null|10432: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.areel.android/0x7f0b0044 vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))

Comment: Why are you not setting up the stuff in onStartCommand? Just curious, as I'm just starting to work with foreground services and all the examples I've found use @Override onStartCommand

Comment: Is there any documentation suggesting only this way, becuase no other way is working for images and there isn't any guildlines in docuemenatation. This drove me crazy for one day and solved my problem just now.

Answer (score 16):

WARNING!

The only correct way to update notification is to recreate RemoteViews before each NotificationManager#notify.  Why? There's a memory leak leading to TransactionTooLargeException, as it has been reported in those questions:

- [TransactionTooLargeException on Samsung S7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813297/transactiontoolargeexception-on-samsung-s7)
- [TransactionTooLargeException while notify notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284000/transactiontoolargeexception-while-notify-notification)
- [Android notification manager TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087779/android-notification-manager-transactiontoolargeexception)
- and in my case

Each call on RemoteViews such as setViewVisibility(...) and so on adds corresponding action to queue of actions are to be applied. After notify the remote view is inflated and actions are actually applied. But the queue is not cleared!

Take a look at screenshot taken during debugging this case.

[image: enter image here]

There I'm updating audio player notification with data coming from ViewModel. Application is stopped on line #81 and you can see the RemoteViews instance that has array of actions with size 51! But I only switched audio track twice and pressed pause! Of course I had to observe application crash with TransactionTooLargeException after a while.

Shallow research confirmed there's no public API to directly or indirectly clear actions queue, so the only way to update notification view is to hold its state separately and recreate RemoteViews instance passed to Notification.Builder, anyway this doesn't overload UI thread a lot

Comment: Man, you have saved me a day! Thank you.
I thought that I have implemented cool optimization, which could save memory. But it brought more harm.

Comment: @Max Elkin: what does this mean? should we do startForeground(ID, notification); instead of NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification)?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to call `NotificationManager.notify(id, notification)` to let Notification System know that you want to update the notification view. Here's the docs link http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html.

Have a method which returns Notification object.

```
private Notification getNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder) {
    RemoteViews mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
    // Update your RemoteViews
    mBuilder.setContent(mRemoteView);
    Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
    // set mNotification.bigContentView if you want to
    return mNotification;

}

private void refreshNotification() {
    mNotificationManager.notify(getNotification(mNotificationBuilder),
                        NOTIFICATION_ID);
    // mNotificationBuilder is initialized already
}
```

Also, note that `bigContentView` and `RemoteViews` are not completely redrawn. If some of the elements of bigContentView has visibility set to `GONE`, and if you want to show it the next time, you have to explicitly set visibility to `VISIBLE`.

Comment: Your both answers have finally helped me, thank you. @Anggrayudi H asnswered first so he deserves the 50 points reputation. Froyo answer is simply nice thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store `Notification` object, but the `Notification.Builder` object. Produce new notification every time before pushing it to

```
NotificationManager.notify( id, notification );
```