# Android - Service and notifications creations

Tags: android, notifications

It's from this morning I'm struggling with this issue (at least for me it's an issue)
My scenario is the following one:
I built an Android background service who is listening on a MQTT topic. When this service receives a MQTT message, it creates a notification for the user.
My service is able in listening and receivng the MQTT messages. What I'm not able in doing is to display my own notification layout and click on the notification in order to view the notification detail
I'm using the following software versions:

- android:

  - compilesdkversion: 21
  - minSdkVersione: 16
  - targetSdkVersion: 21
- MQTT Client: PAHO 1.0.2

In my service when I estabilish the connection with the mqttTopic I use my own implementation of interface org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback

I pass to this interface the service instance who received the mqtt message.
In the callback I want to create a notification by using my own layout
This is the code I wrote:

**Involved method (currentService is the service instance)**

```
   private void notifyUser(Allarme amp) {
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(currentService.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_visualizza_notifica);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(currentService, VisualizzaNotificaActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(IConstants.NOTIFICA_DATA, amp);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(currentService, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(currentService);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.warning);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setOngoing(false);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker(currentService.getString(R.string.notifica_ticker));
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setContent(remoteView);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.data_notifica_text_id, DateUtil.formatMillisDate(amp.getDataNotifica()));
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.data_ricezione_notifica_text_id, DateUtil.formatMillisDate(amp.getDataRicezioneNotifica()));
        TipoAllarme tmp = amp.getTipoAllarme();
        if (tmp != null) {
            String tipoNotifica = tmp.getCodiceAllarme() + " - " + tmp.getDescrizioneAllarme();
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tipo_notifica_text_id, tipoNotifica);
        }
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.descrizione_notifica_text_id, amp.getDescrizioneAllarme());
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        nm.notify(IConstants.MQTT_NEW_NOTIFICATION_ARRIVED, notification);
    }
```

**activity_visualizza_notifica.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_visualizza_notifica_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Ciao dalla notifica"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/data_ricezione_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/data_ricezione_notifica_text_id"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_ricezione_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipo_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descrizione_notifica_text_id"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descrizione_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/data_notifica_text_id"
        android:ems="10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**VisualizzaNotificaActivity.java**

```
public class VisualizzaNotificaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View theView = findViewById(R.id.id_dettaglio_notifica);
        Allarme amp = (Allarme) getIntent().getExtras().get(IConstants.NOTIFICA_DATA);
        TextView dataNotifica = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dettaglio_data_notifica_text_id);
        dataNotifica.setText(DateUtil.formatMillisDate(amp.getDataAllarme()));
        TextView dataRicezioneNotifica = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dettaglio_data_ricezione_notifica_text_id);
        dataRicezioneNotifica.setText(DateUtil.formatMillisDate(amp.getDataRicezioneAllarme()));
        TextView descrizione = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dettaglio_descrizione_notifica_text_id);
        descrizione.setText(amp.getDescrizioneAllarme());
        TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa tamp = amp.getTipoAllarme();
        if (tamp != null) {
            TextView tipoAllarme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dettaglio_tipo_notifica_text_id);
            tipoAllarme.setText(tamp.getCodiceAllarme() + " - " + tamp.getDescrizioneAllarme());
        }
        setContentView(theView);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**dettaglio_notifica.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_dettaglio_notifica"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dettaglio_data_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Ciao dalla notifica"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dettaglio_data_ricezione_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dettaglio_data_ricezione_notifica_text_id"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dettaglio_data_ricezione_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dettaglio_tipo_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dettaglio_descrizione_notifica_text_id"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dettaglio_descrizione_notifica_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dettaglio_data_notifica_text_id"
        android:ems="10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By executing this code, I'm able in generating the notification but:

- my own notification layout is not shown; I see a fully blank notification
- when i click on the notification, the VisualizzaNotificaActivity is called but in onCreate method when I call  `View theView = findViewById(R.id.id_dettaglio_notifica);` it always return null

Maybe I'm missing something... but I can't find what I'm missing....
How can I show my own notification layout when I receive the mqtt message? And do I get that null in my VisualizzaNotificaActivity?

Thank you
Angelo

**EDIT: CHANGED IMPLEMENTATION BY USING BroadcastReceiver**

I changed my service implementation by using a BroadcasterReceiver
Basically I wrote this receiver:

```
public class AllarmiMerciPericoloseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG_LOG = AllarmiMerciPericoloseReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    public AllarmiMerciPericoloseReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try
        {
            if( intent.getAction().equals(IConstants.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_MSG) )
            {
                AllarmeMerciPericolose amp = (AllarmeMerciPericolose)intent.getExtras().get(IConstants.NOTIFICA_DATA);
                notifyUser(amp, context);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG_LOG, "Errore nel receiver per le notifiche "+e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    private void notifyUser(AllarmeMerciPericolose amp, Context context) {
        //Preparo la view per le notifiche; si deve utilizzare una RemoteView
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_visualizza_notifica);
        //Indico l'activity da richiamare quando clicco sulla notifica
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, VisualizzaNotificaActivity.class);
        //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //Passo i parametri che l'activity dovrà gestire al suo interno
        notificationIntent.putExtra(IConstants.NOTIFICA_DATA, amp);
        //Apro l'activity indicata in precedenza
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        //Preparo il costruttore della notifica
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        //Inserisco l'icona della notifica
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.warning);
        //Indico quando è creata la notifica
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //Indico se continua; nel nostro caso non lo è perché non riguarda un processo di background e l'utente può decidere di
        //dismettere la notifica stessa
        builder.setOngoing(false);
        //Dismettiamo la notifica
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker(context.getString(R.string.notifica_ticker));
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setContent(remoteView);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        //builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        //Valorizzo i campi della notifica
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.data_notifica_text_id, DateUtil.formatMillisDate(amp.getDataAllarme()));
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.data_ricezione_notifica_text_id, DateUtil.formatMillisDate(amp.getDataRicezioneAllarme()));
        TipoAllarmeMercePericolosa tmp = amp.getTipoAllarme();
        if (tmp != null) {
            String tipoNotifica = tmp.getCodiceAllarme() + " - " + tmp.getDescrizioneAllarme();
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tipo_notifica_text_id, tipoNotifica);
        }
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.descrizione_notifica_text_id, amp.getDescrizioneAllarme());
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(IConstants.MQTT_NEW_NOTIFICATION_ARRIVED, notification);
    }
}
```

In my callback implementation i send a broadcast in this way:

```
private void propagateBroadcastAction( AllarmeMerciPericolose amp )
{
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction(IConstants.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_MSG);
broadcastIntent.putExtra(IConstants.NOTIFICA_DATA, amp);
currentService.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

But my custom notification is not shown; I attach what is showed as notification to the user (in my emulator)[image: showed Notification Layout]

As you can see, the notification is created but the layout is empty....
Any idea on what I'm missing?

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: Have you tried this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30771421/3922207

Comment: @AnggrayudiH thank you for your answer. I tried it and I have the same result.....

Comment: Try `NotificationCompat.Builder`, and see what happens.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH sadly I get the same result also by using the `NotificationCompact.Builder`... it's getting really frustrating