# Android notification manager TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using a foreground service with ongoing notification which updates very frequently.

When the service launches I initialize the notification manager with the notification builder and keep all the references.

The notification has custom layout with buttons. Each time the user presses a button I update the remote views and call the *notificationManager.notify(service_id, notificationBuilderCompat.build())*.

Eventually after many clicks I receive TransactionTooLargeException error with the size of the data parcel in bytes. Each *notify()* adds more bytes to this number.

What is the best approach to deal with this?

Demo of the code used:

```
class MyService: LifecycleService() {

var notificationBuilderCompat: NotificationCompat.Builder
var notificationManager: NotificationManager
var viewModel: ViewModel
val FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 10
val EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE"
val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01"

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    // View model that holds the data
    viewModel = ViewModel()

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_INTENT)
    notificationManager = getSytemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // In case of android O
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "notification_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTNACE_MAX)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationBuilderCompat = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
}

ovveride fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId:Int): Int {

    // Received start notification command
    if (intent.action == START_FOREGROUND_ACTION) {
        setupNotification()
        viewModel.observerData.observe(this, Observer { data ->
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, data)

            // This handles the update with the new data, and also where the exception happens
            notificationManager.notify(FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notificationBuilderCompat.build())
        })
    } else {
        stopForground(true)
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
        stopSelf()
    }
}

fun setupNotification() {
    remoteViews = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.item_notification)

    // Setting all the remote views here
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_app_icon, R.mipmap.ic_luancher)

    // Setting the click event
    val clickIntent = Intent(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_INTENT)
    clickIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, 1)
    val clickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    remoteVies.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button, clickPendingIntent)

    notificationBuilderCompat.setContent(remoteViews)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setTicker("Notificaion on")
        .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setDefaults(0)

    startForeground(FORGROUND_SERVICE, notificationBuilderCompat.build()
}

// This is the broadcast receiver class to handle the click on the notification button
val broadcastReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
    ovveride fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        // Getting the notification type
        val notificationType = intent!!.getIntExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, 0)

        if (notificationType == 1) {
            // Updating the data here which invokes the observer
            viewModel.updateData()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are creating and raising the `Notification`, including how you are updating the `RemoteViews` on each button click.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added stripped code that I use

Comment: 'Each notify() adds more bytes to this number" -- I assume that the difference between two updates is more than just the length of the text that you are putting in `setTextViewText()`. Try temporarily removing the `ImageView` (and the `setImageViewResource()` call) from the `RemoteViews` and see what happens. Does it fail around the same time as before, or does it take a lot longer to fail when there is on `ImageView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Removing the `setImageViewResource()` allowed few more click before the exception. But the issue is still there and I can't really remove the image as I need it for the notification layout. I can't really understand why the notification accumulates bytes with each `notify()` instead of just clearing the old data. This is issue happens only for android 7.0+ but that is most of my users

Comment: Something about what you are doing must be stacking up notification copies that are part of the transaction. I have no idea why. The image-removal test confirms that (if removing the image didn't change things, then we'd be headed down another path). You might try some other experiments to get a handle on the boundaries of the problem (e.g., switch to Java from Kotlin, switch to `Notification.Builder` from `NotificationCompat.Builder`).

Comment: @IlyaSosis Did you find a way to handle this ?

Comment: @JaswanthManigundan I solved it for 99% for my users by 2 steps:
1. Made sure when I call notify I change only what needed. I removed all the unnecessary `remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, data)` that I had.
2. I called the `setupNotification()` function each time it made scene. looks like it reseted transaction size and allowed me to call more `notify()` afterwards