# TransactionTooLargeException on Samsung S7

Tags: android-notifications, samsung-galaxy, android-remoteview

one of my apps is throwing the following exception on an Samsung S7:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser 
(NotificationManager.java:342)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:292)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:276)
at 
org.mypapp.test.service.NotificationReceiverRemoteViews.updateNotification 
(NotificationReceiverRemoteViews.java:202)
at org.mypapp.test.service.NotificationReceiverRemoteViews.onReceive 
(NotificationReceiverRemoteViews.java:63)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts 
(LocalBroadcastManager.java:308)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000 
(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage 
(LocalBroadcastManager.java:118)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6642)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: 
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:628)
at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag 
(INotificationManager.java:899)
at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser 
(NotificationManager.java:336)
```

Here the code at line 202:

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

I also use an Samsung S7 and I have never gotten that error. I can't reproduce the error with the ansdroid studio emulator either. So I don't know how to fix an error I can't reproduce.
Any idea?

Comment: Still no answers D:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update Notification with RemoteViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789588/how-to-update-notification-with-remoteviews)

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that you update RemoteViews instance before NotificationManager#notify instead of recreating a new one thus producing memory leak. I described this case in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222877/9903092)

Comment: what does this mean? should we do startForeground(ID, notification); instead of NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification)?