# Add icon at the end of body text in Local notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-bitmap

How to add small image(icon) at end of notification(Local notification) body.
I am using **NotificationCompat.Builder** to create notification.I want to add small icon at the end of notification body.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `spannable` String because `setContentText(CharSequence message)` accepts `CharSequence`.

```
  String msg="Hello world";
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(msg);
    ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.app_icon), msg.length()-1, msg.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

And add it to message in notification builder.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder  notification
                = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(ssb))
                .setContentTitle("Hello")
                .setContentText(ssb);
```

I haven't tested it. But i think it should work. Watch out for index.

Comment: Your code add image to string,If I set string to textview works fine but in notification I am not getting image.

Comment: Yeah as i said i have not tested it . Its weird i though it should work with `CharSequence`. Thx for clarification . You should move forward with [RemoteView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)). Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NotificationCompat.Builder#setCustomContentView(RemoteViews)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)). In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789588/how-to-update-notification-with-remoteviews) you can see an example.

Take into account that the notification template has changed in Android N if you go that route, and usually the users expect a consistent UI. See [Android N: Introducing upgraded Notifications](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92)