# Is it posible to rotate ImageView in Notification?

Tags: java, android

I have notification with image. Now I want to update notification and rotate this image, but my method doesn't work:

```
RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_expanded);

// ...

notificationLayoutExpanded.setInt(R.id.notification_arrow, "setRotation", 90);
```

It's throws:

```
android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.ImageView doesn't have method: setRotation(int)
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can rotate the image and post the notification again with the rotated image.. Use same notification id to update the notification.

Comment: But how can I edit RemoteViews?

Comment: You don't update them directly, you need to update the notification itself.. Refer to this question if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789588/how-to-update-notification-with-remoteviews