# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException for ForegroundService notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

I'm writing an android app that tracks the user's location and shows the distance, time and price of the trip in a notification, all this tracked in a `ForegroundService`. The service tracks the location, price and the time, and I'm updating the notification every second.
I get this `TransactionTooLargeException` in production for the very first notification update, it only happens on Samsung devices running Android 8.0+.

This is what's happening:

I call the `start` method from the service:

```
public void start(MeasureService service) {
    service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(0, 0, 0));
}
```

I call the `update` method from the service:

```
public void update(int price, float meters, long time) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(price, meters, time));
}
```

Actually, these calls are called right after one another, the crash is coming from the `update` method. Can this (calling them one after the other) be a problem?

this is the `getNotification`:

```
private Notification getNotification(int price, float meters, long seconds) {
    if (mNotificationBuilder == null) {
        createNotificationBuilder();
    }
    return mNotificationBuilder
            .setCustomContentView(getSmallView(price))
            .setCustomBigContentView(getBigView(price, seconds, meters))
            .build();
}
```

where the `getSmallView` and `getBigView` methods are like this:

```
private RemoteViews getSmallView(int price) {
    String priceText = ...;
    mSmallView.setTextViewText(R.id.price, priceText);
    return mSmallView;
}

private RemoteViews getBigView(int price, long seconds, float meters) {
    String priceText = ...;
    String timeText = ...;
    String distanceText = ...;
    mBigView.setTextViewText(R.id.price, priceText);
    mBigView.setTextViewText(R.id.time, timeText);
    mBigView.setTextViewText(R.id.distance, distanceText);
    return mBigView;
}
```

and this is how I create the `notificationBuilder`:

```
private void createNotificationBuilder() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        ((NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    mNotificationBuilder = mNotificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(getOpenMeasurePageIntent());
}
```

and the `getOpenMeasurePageIntent`:

```
private PendingIntent getOpenMeasurePageIntent() {
    Intent launchMeasureIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    launchMeasureIntent.setAction(...);
    launchMeasureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, launchMeasureIntent, 0);
}
```

This is the crash log I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 560988 bytes
16  at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(NotificationManager.java:319)
17  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:284)
18  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:268)
19  at com.myapp.service.measure.MyNotification.void update(int,float,long) <- this is called from the timer
```

I found a lot of similar issues online, but they are usually about passing big chunks of data in the intent, which I believe I'm not doing.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789588/how-to-update-notification-with-remoteviews/53222877

Comment: Have you tried starting foreground service with normal notification (without remote view)?

Comment: can you add crash logs?

Comment: that usually happens when you have a large amount of data that is being transferred, as you are updating notification frequently, you should try to update the notification only when there is actual change, also have a look at https://medium.com/@mdmasudparvez/android-os-transactiontoolargeexception-on-nougat-solved-3b6e30597345, perhaps this can help you in understanding the issue...

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in updating Notification every seconds.

**Solution**

i suggest you should update notification only when data likes(distance, price) changed.

Comment: I'm updating it every second because I'm showing the time passed but I'll round it to minutes and try it out!

Comment: you can  use other way for time passed. Like handler all that

Comment: I would still need to pass the time to the notification in the transaction

Comment: There's a [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer) widget which you can use to count HH:MM:SS in remote views. On Android 6+ it can also count down.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue on Android 13 (LineageOS 20).

Ended up acquiring about 900 notifications in KDEConnect alone, which ended up preventing the phone from receiving phone calls (they would receive, but not even wake the phone up, no way to accept them as no notification would pop up), Clock alarms wouldn't trigger other than play the sound, and notifications from all other apps wouldn't arrive.

Simply swiping the KDEConnect tile froze the phone for about 10 seconds and everything resumed as normal.

Generating hundreds of notifications still looks like a no go and if you are getting this while developing, it's probably worth trying to clear the existing notifications.

Getting the notification amount through `adb` and `bash`:

```bash
$ adb shell dumpsys notification | grep NotificationRecord | wc -l
937
```

Logcat from A13:

```yaml
E NotificationAssistants: unable to notify assistant (enqueued): android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy@16acbc
E NotificationAssistants: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 535556 bytes
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy.onNotificationEnqueuedWithChannel(INotificationListener.java:599)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$NotificationAssistants.onNotificationEnqueuedLocked(NotificationManagerService.java:10477)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$NotificationAssistants.-$$Nest$monNotificationEnqueuedLocked(Unknown Source:0)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$EnqueueNotificationRunnable.run(NotificationManagerService.java:7543)
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E NotificationAssistants:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:965)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:650)
E NotificationAssistants:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E NotificationAssistants:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:914)
```