# How to pass the multiple sensor values to the notification bar in android when the app is in the background

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-sensors, background-service, light-sensor

I am a newbie in android sensors and notifications. I am working with sensor data(light, proximity, accelerometer, and gyroscope sensor). My goal is to make an app that will be displaying four sensor values in four different card views. I have done that properly. But I am getting stuck with how to run that app in the background after closing the app from the task manager and how the four live sensor values display in the notification bar. I am not getting a proper solution over the internet that makes sense. I need help to solve the problem.

> code:

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        LightSensorXvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        LightSensorYvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        LightSensorZvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));


    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        PorximitySensorXvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        PorximitySensorYvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        PorximitySensorZvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));

    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        AccelerometerXvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        AccelerometerYvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        AccelerometerZvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));

    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        gyroscopeXvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        gyroscopeYvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        gyroscopeZvalue.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));
    }

}
```

Comment: How should the app function while it is running in the background?

Comment: The app shall be running sensor value in the background and It will just display the updated x, y, and z-axis values all-time in the notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

- You will need Custom Notification (reference: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification) to create something custom, because default Notification only supports an Icon and a Title + other 2 lines of simple text
- In additional you will need RemoteView to control this custom layout (reference: [How to update Notification with RemoteViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789588/how-to-update-notification-with-remoteviews)) and update values one by one
- At the end, when a valid/single/static Notification is working well, you can create a Service (reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), that continue to works even when the App is in background, where to update Custom view via RemoteView